# Is MediaProtocolCommand.Listener onCompleted called when it fails to load a video?

Tags: chromecast

I am on purpose sending a video with a format that is not supported to my receiver app. I see the following message on the chromcast console:

> [  8.188s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Sending message:
>   ["ramp",{"cmd_id":1,"type":"RESPONSE","status":{"event_sequence":10,"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2}}}]
>   from ws://localhost:8008/session?20

How do I receive that on my android app? I know `onComplete` for the `MediaProtocolCommand.Listener` is called when the video plays fine. The description makes it sound like it would also be called when it doesn't play or am I reading that wrong?

I've also tried looking into the `MediaProtocolCommand` returned by `mMessageStream.loadMedia` on a separate thread in an infinite loop and it never gets its `hasError` set to true. So what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Cast Android SDK isn't parsing these error messages correctly. In the sample Android client, the following exception is thrown with an invalid video URL:

```
   MediaProtocolMessageStream(9088): error parsing message: 
{"type":"RESPONSE", "cmd_id":1,"status":{"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2},
"event_sequence":377}} org.json.JSONException: No value for state
```

This looks like a bug and should be reported to Google.

Comment: I think you are right, I just noticed this on my android logs `08-30 16:26:14.686: ERROR/MediaProtocolMessageStream(5588): error parsing message: {"type":"RESPONSE","cmd_id":1,"status":{"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2},"event_sequence":1764}} org.json.JSONException: No value for state`. Now I just wish google would say something on their issue tracker.